$|S\cap f(S)|$ for bijections $f:\omega\to\omega$ and $S\subseteq \omega$
Is there a bijection $f:\omega\to\omega$ with the following property?

Whenever $S\subseteq \omega$ is infinite such that $\omega\setminus S$ is infinite as well, then $S\cap f(S)$ is finite.


No. Call moiety an infinite subset with infinite complement. Let us show that for every permutation of $\omega$ there is a moiety $S$ with $S\subset f(S)$. So $f(S)\cap S=S$ is infinite.
A permutation of $\omega$ has a cycle decomposition (with cycles of length $\ge 1$ and $\infty$).
If there are infinitely many cycles, there is an invariant moiety $S$ (so $S=f(S)$ in this case). This also holds if there are at least two infinite cycles.
Otherwise, the permutation consists of a single infinite cycle $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ on the complement of a finite subset, with the permutation mapping $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$. But then $S=\{x_n:n\le 0\}$ satisfies $S\subset f(S)$.

PS on an uncountable subset $X$ of cardinal $\alpha$, moiety means subset of cardinal $\alpha$ with complement of cardinal $\alpha$. In this case, every permutation of $X$ has $\alpha$ cycles and hence there is an invariant moiety.
